# Linq to XML Select All Parent and Child Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I'm trying to bind the results of a Linq to XML query to a DataList control and I'm having trouble returning all of the child values. Here's my XML...

```
<categories>
  <category>
    <parent-id>1234</parent-id>
    <parent-name>Parent 1</parent-name>
    <children>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>5678</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 1</child-name>
      </child-cat>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>2824</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 2</child-name>
      </child-cat>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>2831</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 3</child-name>
      </child-cat>
    </children>
  </category>
  <category>
    <parent-id>6398</parent-id>
    <parent-name>Parent 2</parent-name>
    <children>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>5564</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 1</child-name>
      </child-cat>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>2824</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 2</child-name>
      </child-cat>
      <child-cat>
        <child-id>2831</child-id>
        <child-name>Child 3</child-name>
      </child-cat>
    </children>
  </category>
```

Here's my Linq query...

```
var categories = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/app_data/ShoppingCategories.xml"));
        var allCats = from category in categories.Root.Descendants("category")
             select new
                      {
                          parentId = category.Descendants("parent-id").First().Value,
                          parentName = category.Descendants("parent-name").First().Value,
                          childId = category.Descendants("child-cat").First().Value,
                          childName = category.Descendants("child-name").First().Value
                      };
        dtlstCategories.DataSource = allCats; 
        dtlstCategories.DataBind();
```

My output looks like this (I'm only displaying the parent-name and child-name fields, the id fields are being bound to hidden fields)...

Parent 1   Parent 2
Child 1      Child 2

Because I'm using .First() on the child elements I realize this is why only the first are displaying, but I can't seem to figure out how to get them all to display. This is what I'm after...

Parent 1   Parent 2
Child 1      Child 1
Child 2      Child 2
Child 3      Child 3

It seems like I'm pretty close to getting what I want, but I just can't tie it all together. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT

Here's my DataList...

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlstCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dtlstCategories_ItemDataBound" Visible="True" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" ItemStyle-Wrap="True" BorderWidth="0" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="170">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">    
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTopCategoryId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "parentId") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTopCategory" runat="server" CssClass="support" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "parentName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Image ID="imgCatDivider" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnChildCatId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "childId") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkChildName" runat="server" CssClass="support" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "childName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write something like this

```
var allCats = categories.Descendants("child-cat")
    .Select(c => new
    {
        parentId = c.Parent.Parent.Element("parent-id").Value,
        parentName = c.Parent.Parent.Element("parent-name").Value,
        childId = c.Element("child-id").Value,
        childName = c.Element("child-name").Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This gets me closer, but now my output looks like this...  <br />

Comment: @Padraig75  Like what?

Comment: Sorry... pretty new to SO and struggling with putting in the comment. Basically I get a vertical list of Parent 1, Child 1, Parent 1, Child 2, Parent 1, Child 3, etc. Rather than Parent 1, Child 1, Child 2, Child 3

Comment: @Padraig75 I tested this code with your xml (and also fixed missing `</categories>` tag) and it returns valid 6 items...

Comment: Maybe the problem is with my DataList. I just edited the OP to include that.

Comment: @Padraig75 You are extending the question as "how can I display that". This is not the part of your original question. I think, you will be asking another question if I answer this new one...I am not your team mate.Good luck....

Comment: I'm not asking you to be my team mate, just pointing out that your solution wasn't working for my problem. I appreciate your responses. Thanks.

Comment: @Padraig75 it returns the correct `allCats`, So the answer is correct. Your *new* problem is not in your original question. What you do is not a good way of asking question. Ask a good/complete one and get the answer.  Extending it with a new requests is not the way how SO works.....

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct, since that's what you obviously want me to do. You're right in that I did not ask a "complete" question. I should have included my DataList in the OP. Adding that after the fact is the only way I "extended" my question.